# Can someone explain the result of CGRectGetMaxX and CGRectIntersection?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

### Scenario

Assume two non-intersecting rectangles, both 10 points wide and 5 points high. The x/y values in the following schema indicate the coordinates of the corner points of the two rectangles.

```
x/y = 0/0 +------------------+ x/y = 9/0
          |                  |
          |                  |
          |                  |
          |                  |
x/y = 0/4 +------------------+ x/y = 9/4
x/y = 0/5 +------------------+ x/y = 9/5
          |                  |
          |                  |
          |                  |
          |                  |
x/y = 0/9 +------------------+ x/y = 9/9
```

Here's the code to set up these rectangles:

```
CGRect rect1 = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f, 5.0f);
CGRect rect2 = CGRectMake(0.0f, 5.0f, 10.0f, 5.0f);
```

### CGRectGetMaxX

The return value for the `CGRectGetMaxX` Core Graphics function is documented like this:

> The largest value of the x-coordinate for the rectangle.

Here is a code snippet that uses the function:

```
CGFloat maxX = CGRectGetMaxX(rect1);
```

From the documentation, I would expect `maxX` to be 9. However, `maxX` is 10. Huh?

### CGRectIntersection

The return value for the `CGRectIntersection` Core Graphics function is documented like this:

> A rectangle that represents the intersection of the two specified rectangles. If the two rectangles do not intersect, returns the null rectangle. To check for this condition, use CGRectIsNull.

Here is a code snippet that uses the function:

```
CGRect intersectionRect = CGRectIntersection(rect1, rect2);
bool intersectionRectIsNull = CGRectIsNull(intersectionRect);
```

From the documentation, I would expect `intersectionRectIsNull` to be true since `rect1` and `rect2` are clearly not intersecting. However, `intersectionRectIsNull` is false. Huh???

If we examine `intersectionRect` in the debugger, we see this:

```
(CGRect) $0 = origin=(x=0, y=5) size=(width=10, height=0)
```

Yeah, so now it's clear why `CGRectIsNull` is returning false, but why on earth is `intersectionRect` not this?

```
(CGRect) $0 = origin=(x=+Inf, y=+Inf) size=(width=0, height=0)
```

### Question

Can someone explain why the documentation of these functions is NOT wrong? I must be missing something, but for the life of me I cannot see what it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your diagram is incorrect. It doesn't match your `CGRectMake` calls.

A rectangle that is 10 wide with an origin of 0 will have a max X of 10, just as you are getting.

The `9` in your diagram should be `10` and the `4` in your diagram should be `5`.

Given the two calls to `CGRectMake`, the two rectangles share a common side. There is no gap between them.

Remember, 0 + 10 is 10, not 9 and 0 + 5 is 5, not 4.

Comment: Eh? `CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 5)` says the rectangle is 10 points wide and begins at coordinate 0. So the first point is at coordinate 0, the second point is at coordinate 1, the third point is at coordinate 2, [...], the tenth point is at coordinate 9. No?

Comment: @herzbube No. Width/height can't be represented with a single "point", you need to have two points to calculate the distance to determine those measurements. Think about it like any other height/width measurement. The distance from 0 feet to 1 foot is *1 foot*, even though you are talking about two "points". So, in your case, it is 10 points wide - (0->1, 1->2, 2->3....9->10), which is 10 values.